# WebView embed video always have white borders around the video

Tags: android, iframe, webview, react-native

I'm trying to put youtube video iframe inside WebView component and it works great but when I want to set the size of the WebView component to match the iframe size it always leaves weird borders around the video. also what is really weird is that setting iframe width to screen width makes this huge gap on the right site. I tried a lot of things like wrapping the WebView in View tag and set this View component height to iframe height but it always leaves the borders on top and bottom which causes the WebView to have a scroll bar on the site.

Here's the image:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7geT2.png)

Here's my code

```
render() {
    return(
            <WebView
            source={{html: `<html><body><iframe width="${this.SCREEN_WIDTH}" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ojmk5tSj0sE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></html></body>` }}
            style={{height: 20}}
            >
            </WebView>          
    )
}
```

as you can see I tried here to put height = 20 but id didn't change anything I can still see the whole video. I tried combinations with *automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}* and
                *scalesPageToFit={true}*. I also tried:

```
 marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
```

inside the Iframe with no results.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658260/iframe-border-showing-in-webview-react-native) post from someone having the same problem but it's not answered

It seems like easy thing but it prevents me from progressing with my app. Im 
100% sure someone already made embed iframe with 0 borders and margins in react-native :P. If you saw some examples please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

body has default value of margin and padding.
For the case which dont want any border. just set margin and padding to zero.

**For example:**

From:

```
<html><body>....</body></html>
```

To:

```
<html><body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">...</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for some of my embedded content :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the unnecessary gaps come from the `body` tag which wraps the iframe. You should reset margins and paddings on html and body tags the same way you usually do it on web. FYI, you can inspect the code and styles of you WebView simply by opening Safari and  clicking on  Develop -> iPhone simulator -> YOUR WEBVIEW (it will probably be displayed as about:blank). Then,

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add to WebView’s styles `backgroundColor: “transparent”`